# Silverlight 2.0 with IE6 + compression bug

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-6

Our silverlight application will not run on IE6 if we have IIS dynamic compression
On. However If we turn compression off the site works.

Turning compression off is not an option for us.

We have tried everything in the post
http://otoole.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/18/ but it didn't fix the issue. The problem does not occur on IE7.

It appears this is a Microsoft bug with IE, but Microsoft will not post this as a bug, and has no to little information about the cause of the problem.

Did anyone have this problem? If you know how to solve it… please write back.

Comment: I think by about silverlight version 12.0 they will some of the bugs worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off compression just for the page itself, that'll allow you to keep compression on everything else.

Alternatively does the steps detailed [here](http://silverlight.net/forums/p/87700/204665.aspx) help?